# how to know which RedirectToAction I need?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I have created a base controller which my 2 other controllers are derived from, to avoid code duplication.

I **had** 2 ActionResult's in these controllers that are about 80 lines, and 79 lines are the same. The only difference is the redirect action at the end of the ActionResult.

My question is: Is there a way to know which `RedirectToAction` need to be called, i.e. which controller we need to return to?

Comment: "2 ActionResult's in these controllers" implies the methods are in the derived controllers.  But your later comments you are saying in the base controller.  Please stub out what functions you have in base controller and derived controllers so it is clear and we don't have to guess.

Comment: I changed one word, now in bold. Hope it's clear now :) I had these methods in the derived controllers, now they are in the base controller.

Comment: "now they are in the base controller" That information is not in your question.  You state there's two methods in derived controllers, and you don't say what is in the base controller.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, avoid using base controllers unless you absolutely need them.  They tend to become dumping grounds for sharing stuff and you end up with tons of stuff that only applies to a couple of your controllers just because it was easier.

It's just best to make it a policy of not using them, and only make exceptions when you absolutely have to.

Besides that, Controllers really should be lean.  If your Controller is 80 lines of code, it tells me you're doing business logic in your controller.  You should probably have that logic in your business layer.  What's more, you're probably violating the Single Responsibility Principal.

You can achieve the same result without a base controller by utilizing a helper class.  For instance, you can do something like this:

```
public static class MyHelper
{
    public static Foo DoSomething() { return new Foo();  }
}

public class MyController1 : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = MyHelper.DoSomething();
        return File(...);
    }
}

public class MyController2 : Controller
{
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        var result = MyHelper.DoSomething();
        return JSON(...);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Not directly, you might check for some condition in your model and wrap the redirect around an `if`. Or, add a query string parameter:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(MyModel model, string actionRedirect = null)
```

Comment: The method calling the ActionResult in the base controller is also in the base controller :) So I have no way to change that querystring parameter.. Any way to work around that?

Comment: The idea is that I can use that actionRedirect parameter to create an if statement and select the proper redirect action